# Virtualbox not allowing 64-bit guests on mac os

Tags: macos, virtualbox, macos-big-sur, virtualbox-guest-additions

I recently got a new computer - macbook, 2020, m1 chip, running Big Sur, and I wanted to install a windows 10 64-bit guest on virtualbox on it. However, no 64 bit options of any kind appear in the menu when I try to create a new machine. On my old computer, virtualbox still seems totally capable of creating and running a 64-bit guest. I noticed other people had this issue, but there was no clear explanation for how to fix this if the host is a mac. There seemed only to be fixes for Windows Users. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Did you find an answer?